# How to horizontally center aligning a label to fit all screen size in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I try to horizontally centering a label for iPhone5, iPhone6, iPhone6+ with autolayout and size class in swift.

[image]

iPhone6 screen:
[image]

iPhone6+ screen:[image]

iPhone 5s screen:

[image]

When i adjusted constraints the label is center aligned for iPhone5s only.it is slightly left aligned for iPhone6 and iPhone6+ screen.please correct me where i went wrong.any help will be appreciated,thanks in advance

Comment: Are you cool with a code answer or does it have to be IB? This would be super easy with just one line of code.

Comment: please give your answer for both.i  will try it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all remove all the constraints from the label and put the label where you want to display it after that click on the label into storyBoard and click on Resolve Auto LayOut Issues at the right hand side below and after that click on **Add Missing Constraints** like shown below.

[image]

This works for me correctly.

Comment: i am getting wrong result.can u send me ur sample project?